# Updating specific package.json in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, node-modules

I was wondering if it is possible to update a specific package.json in the node_modules? The reason is because I am getting an invalid hook call error in my code and I believe it is because I have mismatching Reacts. I ran the duplicate react test on the invalid hook call page and I got false, which means I have two reacts. After using "npm ls react" I saw this error:

```
react@17.0.2 deduped invalid: "^16.4.2" from node_modules/redux-form
```

In my node_modules/redux-form under peerDependencies I have:

```
"react": "^16.4.2"
```

instead of:

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the fix to my error, but invalid hook call errors are confusing to fix so I'm hoping this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebuild your `node_modules`

1. make a backup
2. remove node modules `rm -rf node_modules/`
3. update your packages in `package.json`
4. rebuild `npm install` or `npm i`